# Destructive nature operation in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clone a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python)

I found some interesting results

```
a = [1, 2] 
b=a 
b.append(3) 
print a, b

#=> [1,2,3] [1,2,3]


a = [1, 2] 
b=a 
b += [3] 
print a, b

#=> [1,2] [1,2,3]
```

It seems like some operation have change the referenced value, some create  a new. I remember in Ruby it can use `!` to indicate which method have this destructive nature. Does python have the similar way to let me distinguish them? or providing a list to show all the most commonly used one?

Comment: `b += a` operator is the same as `b = b + a` where `+` is concatenation, which creates a new object. Python documentation is your only friend.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti, I dont think it's a duplicate but the linked question is kind of a answer to this one.

Comment: @dzonder: Is this explicitly mentioned somewhere? Because according to the [data model docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__): *"These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self)"*. But it might be different for sequence types...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is any kind of indicator (except looking for `id(b) != id(a)` ).

Comment: **Oh**, which Python version are you using? I get `[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]` as output in Python 2.7.3.

Comment: @FelixKling _"If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods."_. I didn't find `__iadd__` in list methods in my Python environment.

Comment: @dzonder: Yeah, I saw that too. I did not expect a version where `__iadd__` does not exist. Which version are you using?

Comment: The syntax for augmented assignments was only added in 2.2 (http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.2/NEWS.txt) and by then in-place `__iadd__` had already been implemented for `list`. So it seems no version of Python should exist where the `[1,2]+=[3]` would have to fall back to `[1,2]+[3]`. Something is weird.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. It seems that what was posted here is not the actual results.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to some existing answers here, the real reason actually the opposite. `+=` is meant to be an in-place operator that modifies *self* in Python. But there's some catch to it.

---

For immutable types such as tuples and strings, `my_tuple += (1, )` is equivalent to `my_tuple = my_tuple + (1, )` which creates a *new* object then assigns it to `my_tuple`:

```
>>> my_tuple = (1,2,3)
>>> t = my_tuple
>>> t += (2,)
>>> t
(1, 2, 3, 2)
>>> my_tuple
(1, 2, 3)
```

This is because immutable types such as tuples and strings do not implement `__iadd__` (you can check by `dir(tuple)` for example). And in this case it falls back to use [`__add__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) instead. This will create a new object and assign it to the original variable.

---

For some mutable types such as lists and dictionaries, however, `__iadd__` is implemented, and `+=` will be calling it instead:

```
>>> inspect.getdoc(list.__iadd__)
'x.__iadd__(y) <==> x+=y'

>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> b += [4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So for mutable types, this in-place operation is performed (by modifying *self*) and the [original object will be updated](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/operator.html#inplace-operators).

Comment: Your last sentence seems incorrect. `list` does implement `__iadd__`, and `list.__add__` is not the same as `extend`. `list.__iadd__` is (almost) the same as `extend`.

Comment: @interjay you are right, it should be the `tuple` that does not have it implemented. I have updated my answer to correct it. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

There is no naming convention.

However, the use is that methods that modify the object return None, and those that create a new object will return said object.